# How to send or bind data to child component before it's constructor is called in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have parent and child component in angular 2 where I want to bind data to child directive and get the data in constructor and pass that data to a service call.

**Parent Template -**

```
<child-comp [id]="id"></child-comp>
```

**Child constructor -**

```
@Input() id : number;
constructor(service : Service){
      this.service.getData(this.id).subscribe((model: Model) => {
                // logic ...
  });
}
```

I am not able to get bound data (id) in child constuctor. However, I am able to get the data in ngOnChanges() life cycle hook. Please let me know how get around this?

Note - I'm not able to get the data initially when the component loads, neither in ngOnInit nor constructor. I am able to get it once the component is initialized in ngOnChanges.

Answer (score -1):

You have to get your bound data inside `ngOnInit` of your Child constructor:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.service.getData(this.id).subscribe((model: Model) => {
                // logic ...
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to get the data initially when the component loads, neither in ngOnInit nor constructor. I am able to get it once the component is initialized in ngOnChanges.

Comment: From parent when value in `id` is set ? post your parent code related to it here.